# How do I set the asp label text with the data in JQuery returned from the web service call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

Before posting this questions I was looking at some solutions, but they seem not to be too helpful.

So, here is my question and I hope to find the solution.

I tried to set my label to the data returned from the `web service` call, but it seems like nothing I tried so far has worked.

I used to display the data in a `textbox` and it worked fine.

But the requirements has changed and I need to show the label inside of the `div` tag.

So, I wanted to display the `label` first before working on a `div` logic.

So, for this example I will show html for `textbox` and for the label inside of the table to see the difference.

Textbox display the data and label does not.

I have the following html after it generated on the page:

```
<div id="dv_ImportantNote" style="visibility: visible;">
     <div style="overflow: auto; height:80px; width:505px;">
      <table>
          <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <textarea name="ctl00$cphBody$txtImportantNote" rows="2" cols="20" readonly="readonly" id="txtImportantNote" class="txtImportantNote"></textarea>
                  </td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                     <span id="cphBody_lblImportantNote" class="lblImportantNote"></span>                                
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then I have a service call that returns the data into the `result`.

After that I'm trying to display the data for textbox and the label.

I show 2 options for the sake of demonstration. The `textbox` shows the data on the UI but the label does not.

```
if (result.length > 0) {
    $('#dv_ImportantNote').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#txtImportantNote').val(result[0].Note);
    $('#cphBody_lblImportantNote').innerHTML(result[0].Note)
}
```

I tried different options with: `.html()`, `.text()`,`.val()`, and nothing seems to be working

What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1):

ASP.NET Webforms auto generates IDs for controls in the web page

This label will have `"cphBody_lblImportantNote"`as its ID.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblImportantNote" />
```

If you'd like to update with JQuery, you can use this.

```
$('#<%# =lblImportantNote.ClientID %>').text(result[0].Note);
```

`<%# =Control.ClientID %>` gives you the rendered ID for your control, this way jQuery can update it.

To update Labels use `.text(value)` in jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I already found out the problem

Comment: Injecting IDs into your Javascript makes for unmaintainable code in the long term.  It's better to assign some arbitrary class name to the elements that are being referenced, and then use the class name in the selector for jQuery.  This keeps the code much more cleaner.